# Use jquery countdown in php Foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

AM trying to use jquery in a php foreach loop for a countdown but it only works on the newest row of the foreach and displays no countdown for the other items of the foreach

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <?php 
        $nota = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_order($_SESSION['id'],'delivery_status');                
        foreach($nota as $pa):
        $dev = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('name','delivery_status','delivery_status_id',$pa['delivery_status']);?>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#count<?php echo $pa['trackingnumber'] ?>"><button class="btn btn-info">
    <p><?php echo $dev; ?></p>
    <h4 style="color:#fff;"><div id="countdown"></div></h4>
    <p>Hour  min   sec</p>
    </button></a>


<script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#countdown').countdown('<?php echo $pa['delivery_time']; ?>', function(event) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
        });
    </script>
    <?php include ('account_count_modal.php'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why? Because ID's must be unique by definition...change to class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated your code using counter as below:

```
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <?php 
    $nota = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_order($_SESSION['id'],'delivery_status');  
    $counter = 0;              
    foreach($nota as $pa):
        $counter++;
        $dev = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('name','delivery_status','delivery_status_id',$pa['delivery_status']);
    ?>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#count<?php echo $pa['trackingnumber'] ?>"><button class="btn btn-info">
        <p><?php echo $dev; ?></p>
        <h4 style="color:#fff;"><div id="countdown<?php echo $counter;?>"></div></h4>
        <p>Hour  min   sec</p>
        </button></a>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#countdown<?php echo $counter;?>').countdown('<?php echo $pa['delivery_time']; ?>', function(event) {
                $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
            });
        </script>
    <?php include ('account_count_modal.php'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what problem was or what was done to fix it. Code only answers are not very valuable. People shouldn't need to be human diff tools to understand what you have done

Comment: thanks, ise where my problem was, had to make it unique. it works